# How to dump data (couple of millions of rows) formatted in a human friendly way into a relational database?

Tags: database, persistence, analytics

For example:

Given:

- An output of the `dumpheap` WinDbg command containing about 3.5 million rows.

Needed:

- Break into columns and dump it into a relational database

The output looks like this:

```
Opened log file 'c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff6c9c16b8.log'
0:000> !dumpheap -mt 00007fff6c9c16b8
         Address               MT     Size
0000009347e51018 00007fff6c9c16b8       30
0000009347e51038 00007fff6c9c16b8       46
0000009347e51068 00007fff6c9c16b8       30
0000009347e51088 00007fff6c9c16b8       56
0000009347e510c0 00007fff6c9c16b8       30
0000009347e510e0 00007fff6c9c16b8       94
0000009347e51140 00007fff6c9c16b8       30
...
0000009de2474cd8 00007fff6c9c16b8       52
0000009de2474d10 00007fff6c9c16b8       44
0000009777e71070 00007fff6c9c16b8   130594

Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007fff6c9c16b8  3645317  28984711048 System.String
Total 3645317 objects
0:000> .logclose
Closing open log file c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff6c9c16b8.log
```

As you can see there are a few lines at the beginning and at the end to be ignored, the rest are just three values delimited with spaces and aligned to look nice for a human. This is not a machine friendly format.

Of course, I have a C# code to dump it into a Sql Server database. One has to:

1. Parse command line arguments (and be able to output the help on them)
2. Create a new database or reset an existing one with the schema matching our needs. This should include a Table UDT for the records we are going to dump into the database.
3. Parse the output into three columns and write into the database in batches using TVP

Not a big deal for a programmer, but may be a show stopper for a Support person, who can analyse a core dump, but does not write non trivial code as part of his/her duties.

So, my question is are there any tools that can help out here? The relational database can be the Sql Server or any other free relational database (Sql Server is not free, but we use it already).